# How can I use the CLEVELS statement to specify my class levels for the surveyimpute function in SAS 9.4?

Tags: sas, survey, imputation

I am using the following code:
 `***Trouleshoot***; PROC surveyimpute DATA=data_Impute METHOD=FEFI varmethod=jackknife; class peopleHH (CLEVELS=(1 2 3 4 5 6 7)); VAR peopleHH; Strata sdmvstra; Cluster sdmvpsu; Weight WTSA2YR; output out=survey_svi_imputed fractionalweights=FracWgt outjkcoefs=Ojkc; RUN;`

The variable "peopleHH" has 7 possible responses (1-7). I thought I should assign these using CLEVELS in the "class" statement, but I keep getting syntax errors.  I have tried all sorts of formats, but I always receive the same syntax error:

```
`PROC surveyimpute DATA=workdatasviImpute METHOD=FEFI varmethod=jackknife;
2179  class peopleHH (CLEVELS=(1 2 3 4 5 6 7));
                  -------
                  22
                  76
ERROR 22-322: Syntax error, expecting one of the following: ), DESC, DESCENDING, ORDER.
ERROR 76-322: Syntax error, statement will be ignored.`
```

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Any ideas?

I have tried:

```
`class peopleHH / CLEVELS=(1 2 3 4 5 6 7);`
```

and
`class peopleHH(CLEVELS=1 2 3 4 5 6 7);`

and
`class peopleHH / (CLEVELS=1 2 3 4 5 6 7);`
etc....

I'm just hoping to impute missing data from the peopleHH variable.

Answer (score 0):

`clevels` is used in the `var` statement, not the `class` statement. Per the documentation:

> CLEVELS=k
>
> specifies the number of levels by which to categorize numeric
> variables that are in the VAR statement but not in the CLASS
> statement. The procedure divides the range of these variables into k
> equally spaced bins. You can specify the CLEVELS= option either as a
> global-option or as an individual option.

Setting `peopleHH` as a `class` variable will automatically cause `surveyimpute` to treat its distinct values as unique levels.